# Some files inside folder are not being listed

Tags: php, loops, file, recursion, directory

This below code prints the name of the image and video file inside a folder. Each folder contains only 2 items one image and one video. It works fine when the folders are few; but when i execute this on a path of 100 folders some images or videos  are skipped from being listed. I am not sure what is the problem.

```
<?php
$gfg_folderpath = "C:\wamp\www\Films/";

// CHECKING WHETHER PATH IS A DIRECTORY OR NOT
if (is_dir($gfg_folderpath)) {
    // GETTING INTO DIRECTORY
    $files = opendir($gfg_folderpath); {
        // CHECKING FOR SMOOTH OPENING OF DIRECTORY
        if ($files) {
            //READING NAMES OF EACH ELEMENT INSIDE THE DIRECTORY
            while (($gfg_subfolder = readdir($files)) !== FALSE) {
                // CHECKING FOR FILENAME ERRORS
                if ($gfg_subfolder != '.' && $gfg_subfolder != '..') {
                    // echo "SUBFOLDER--" .$gfg_subfolder . "<br>
                    // "."Files in ".$gfg_subfolder."--<br>";
                    
                    $dirpath = "C:\wamp\www\Films/" . $gfg_subfolder . "/";
                    // GETTING INSIDE EACH SUBFOLDERS
                    if (is_dir($dirpath)) {
                        $file = opendir($dirpath); {
                            if ($file) {
                                        
                                //READING NAMES OF EACH FILE INSIDE SUBFOLDERS
                                while (($gfg_filename = readdir($file)) !== FALSE) {

                                    $numbers = array();
                                    if ($gfg_filename != '.' && $gfg_filename != '..') {
                                        //  $mimeType = mime_content_type($gfg_filename);
                                        if(strtolower(end(explode(".",$gfg_filename))) =="png") {
                                            $vid= $gfg_filename . "<br>";
                                            $numbers[0]=$gfg_filename;
                   
                                        }
                                        if(strtolower(end(explode(".",$gfg_filename))) =="mp4") {
                                            $img= $gfg_filename . "<br>";
                                            $numbers[1]=$gfg_filename;
                                        }
                
                                        echo  $numbers[0]. "<br>".$numbers[1]. "<br>";      
                                    }
                
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    echo "<br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

[image: O/P WORKING]

[image: O/P NOT WORKING]

Comment: You’ve got two `if` statements, throw an `else` in there to see what’s not catching

Comment: You have twice used a `{}` set unnecessary. Here `$file = opendir($dirpath); {` and here `$file = opendir($dirpath); {`

Comment: Big Note You should never place your site in the `c:\wamp\www` folder in WAMPServer, make a sub folder and a Virtual Host to address it. Or place the site in a completely seperate folder if you like.

Comment: I would guess `F_44.mp4` has a trailing space of unprintable character

Comment: My first idea when I saw these deeply nested conditional blocks is: [Spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code). You make it very hard for yourself to understand what is going on. You need all those comments to make sense of it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I thought someone must have been giving away `if`'s and `{}` :)

Comment: I know criticism like I wrote isn't nice, and I also don't offer a solution. I wrote it with the best intentions. Try to read good code written by others. See how they do it. Note how they use functions, classes and exceptions to write simple and readable code while still checking for errors.

Comment: You could add a [trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) before comparing the extension to `"mp4"`. That will remove any whitespace from the extension.

Comment: Have a look at `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`, it can significantly reduce the size of your code and make it more readable by removing the many `if`/`while` layers: https://www.php.net/manual/en/recursivedirectoryiterator.construct.php